# Force tablet browser to use mobile sites

Tags: android

In Android, I need to test my app against a variety of websites. My app needs to view the site's mobile content and not its full desktop content. In Google Chrome for the desktop you can set the user-agent to fake the browser to be seen as a mobile device. But the browser in Android may indicate to the site that it's a desktop size. Is there some way to force Android's browser to retrieve only mobile content?

Comment: This is a server side thing, not client side, I believe. The reason Chrome has that feature is because you're using a desktop, and so sites would normally return desktop versions of stuff for you. But when you contact a site with a mobile device, it's the server that's detecting it and choosing to show you mobile content.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
Are you using a Webview?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)

Comment: No, I launch the default browser with an Intent. I just want it to startup with a user-agent that forces the website to send mobile content instead of the desktop content.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the default?

Comment: Have you not used a 10 inch tablet and viewed a site like cnn? That appears to the server as a desktop browser.

Comment: ok, i was thinking of a smartphone. I can't help you, anyway. Sorry